# Applying regex rule to transform an existing variable/string

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to use a regex rule to transform the contents of a variable.

For example, if I had this value1:

```
value1=this-is-an-example-string
```

And I wanted to create a new value - `value2` - where I use the below regex to isolate the first three words and the hyphens between them:

```
 regex=^\w*-\w*-\w*
```

This regex would correspond to the following in value1:

```
this-is-an
```

How do I use the regex defined in `regex`on value1, to generate a new value (value2) that contains only `this-is-an`.

I tried using the following but it does not work:

```
value2 ==~ value1(regex)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def haystack = 'this-is-an-example-string'
```

Put brackets around the match object you want to capture

```
def needle = haystack =~ /^(\w*-\w*-\w*).*/
```

If there's a match

```
if (needle) {
```

This gets the first capture in match object

```
    assert needle[0][1] == 'this-is-an'
}
```

So

```
def value2 = needle[0][1]
println value2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `==~` operator is for exact matches and returns a `boolean`. One way to do what you want is with the `=~` "find" operator which returns a Matcher and work on that:

```
groovy> value1 = "this-is-an-example-string" 
groovy> regex  = /^\w*-\w*-\w*/ 
groovy> println "Using the findAll method Groovy adds to Matcher" 
groovy> value2 = (value1 =~ regex) 
groovy> println value2 
groovy> println value2.findAll()[0] 
groovy> println "" 
groovy> println "Or indexing directly into the Matcher" 
groovy> value3 = (value1 =~ regex)[0] 
groovy> println value3 
 
Using the findAll method Groovy adds to Matcher
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=^\w*-\w*-\w* region=0,25 lastmatch=]
this-is-an

Or indexing directly into the Matcher
this-is-an
```